# Comparing two date::hh_mm_ss in C++

Tags: c++, datetime

Is it possible to compare two variables of type `date::hh_mm_ss` in Howard Hinnant's date library? I know I can convert them into seconds and perform the comparison but I was wondering if the library provides a built-in function for date, time, or datetime comparison in general.

```
date::hh_mm_ss tod1{std::chrono::hours{10} + std::chrono::minutes{00} + std::chrono::seconds{00}};
date::hh_mm_ss tod2{std::chrono::hours{8} + std::chrono::minutes{00} + std::chrono::seconds{00}};
std::cout << (tod1 < tod2) << "\n";
```

I get `error: no match for ‘operator<’`.

Comment: Why use an additional library which can't do what you want, when the thing you want is built-in into the C++ standard library already? I don't get it. https://godbolt.org/z/Gzs49xedz

Comment: No, it's intended as a formatting tool, on general you're better off using a duration

Comment: Note that `hh_mm_ss` is part of standard library since c++20.

Comment: A reference for the claims in other comments: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/hh_mm_ss): *"It is primarily a formatting tool."* (I'd also mention that `std::hh_mm_ss` is very close to, if not identical to, `date::hh_mm_ss`. The similar names are not a coincidence; the Date library you are looking at was merged into C++20.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare two `hh_mm_ss`'s, call the `to_duration()` member function on each and compare those:

```
std::cout << (tod1.to_duration() < tod2.to_duration()) << "\n";
```

### Rationale for this design

The reason that `hh_mm_ss` doesn't have comparison functions is that it is really just a formatting aid, and not a good type for storing times.  Use `std::chrono::duration` with whatever precision is good for your use case (`seconds`, `microseconds`, etc.) for storing time-of-day.  Such a duration measures the elapsed time since midnight (that could be UTC or some local midnight).

`hh_mm_ss` is a good helper type when you have a `duration` and you want to "extract the fields" of hours, minutes, seconds, and possibly subseconds from that `duration`.  But `duration` is the type you want to use for comparisons, arithmetic, and storage.  It is superior in all of those departments in terms of size, speed and flexibility.

Finally one subtle point that most people miss about `hh_mm_ss` is that it is *not always* exactly equivalent to the `duration` it was constructed from.  Consider this example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    using D = duration<long long, ratio<1, 3>>;
    D d{2};  // 2/3 of a second
    hh_mm_ss hms{d};
    auto d_from_hms = hms.to_duration();
    cout << "d == d_from_hms is " << (d == d_from_hms) << '\n';
    cout << "d = " << d << '\n';
    cout << "d_from_hms = " << d_from_hms << '\n';
    cout << "d - d_from_hms = " << d - d_from_hms << '\n';
}
```

Here I've created a duration type named `D` that is <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> of second.  And a value `d` of that type that holds 2 of them (<sup>2</sup>/<sub>3</sub> of second).  When I construct an `hh_mm_ss` from `d` I do *not* get an exact conversion.  I get an *approximate* conversion:  666666us instead of <sup>2</sup>/<sub>3</sub> of second.  When I convert the `hh_mm_ss` back to a `duration`, it is slightly less than <sup>2</sup>/<sub>3</sub> of second.

[Demo.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NlZsQAChicFDi4Ol)

Output:

```
d == d_from_hms is 0
d = 2[1/3]s
d_from_hms = 666666us
d - d_from_hms = 2[1/3000000]s
```

Why?  Because as a formatting aid, the main job of `hh_mm_ss` is to figure out how to print out the `duration` with a floating point decimal representation for the `seconds` field (if the precision is `seconds`, then no need for the "floating point part").

```
cout << "hms = " << hms << '\n';
```

Output:

```
hms = 00:00:00.666666
```

More examples of this relationship are found [in the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.hms#tab:time.hms.width).  Only those `duration`s that can losslessly convert to a `duration` with a `ratio` that represents a non-positive power of 10 will be represented exactly in an `hh_mm_ss` (`seconds`, `duration<int64_t, ratio<1, 10>>`, `duration<int64_t, ratio<1, 100>>`, `milliseconds`, etc.).